# Make internet explorer load fluently without flickering

Tags: javascript, .net, internet-explorer

I've been searching for a previous version of this question on Stackoverflow, but I couldn't find it. I imagine though that this must have been asked 100's of times, so I'm probably using the wrong searchterms.

My problem is that I have a very busy webpage. A lot of elements are loaded. After this happens the CSS is loaded and the JS does some stuff. This all causes a lot of stuttering which looks very messy. I've made a capture of it and uploaded it here:

http://gfycat.com/WearyPrestigiousFlea

Any solution would be fine, but I do need the postbacks. I need the information in my querystring for a lot of reasons. This page is too complex to fix everything with Ajax. I do not need advice on that matter. However: if there is a trick to mask the loading, or to make it smoother, please share your knowledge :-)

**Edit:**
In answer to one of the comments below: There were no errors. I'm using IE9, which does not have the setting "Pre-load content before refreshing screen" as IE11 does (along with other reasonable browsers). Right now I added "Display: none;" to the body tag and "$("body").show();" in document.ready. It looks a lot better, but still get a lot of "white" between postbacks.

Comment: Hi,
Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "always record developer console error messages".

then navigate to your un-named website.

f12>Console tab to view a listing of javascript error messages... I expect you will have a number of 'Parser reset' errors.' and "unclosed tag" errors

and/or

test your site/page at http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed or 
http://modern.ie/report... these tools will identify rendering and scripting bottlenecks.

Comment: There were no errors. I'm using IE9, which does not have the setting "Pre-load content before refreshing screen" as IE11 does (along with other reasonable browsers). Right now I added "Display: none;" to the body tag and "$("body").show();" in document.ready. It looks a lot better, but still get a lot of "white" between postbacks. Adding this comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now I added "Display: none;" to the body tag and "$("body").show();" in document.ready. It looks a lot better, but still get a lot of "white" between postbacks.

Maybe you can try putting the $("body").show() call inside the **load** event:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    $("body").show();
});
```

The "load" event executes when the page is fully loaded while the "ready" event you used executes when the DOM is ready, so you cannot be sure that all the graphics are already loaded.

Comment: Yep, might be slightly better. Problem is still that while the page is loading, the old content is discarded and the screen turns white. The answer to my original question is probably: its IE9, deal with it.